# Detecting if zoomIn or zoomOut on 'zoomstart'

Tags: leaflet

I wrote a function which, on zoomstart, (should) do_something1 if I zoomIn and do_something2 when I zoomOut:

```
            'var prevzoom = map.getZoom;

            map.on('zoomstart', do_something);
            function do_something(e){

                var currzoom = map.getZoom();
                var diff = currzoom - prevzoom;
                if(diff > 0){do_something1}
                else {do_something2}
                prevzoom = currzoom;'
```

It behaves as follows:
1)when loading, if I zoomOut it do_something2 (and the second, third... time as well
2)when loading if I zoomIn it do_something2 (uncorrectly) but it do_something1 the second, third... time and so on...
3) when I change from ZoomIn to ZoomOut and viceversa the first time it behaves as the previous time and it behaves correctly on the second, third...time when zooming in the same way (i.e. In or Out).

I read in the post "Detecting if is zoom-in or zoom-out with leaflet"  its it not possible to know if zoomIn or Out  when the event zoomstart is triggered.
In my case it seems to work most of the time (which is not good anyway).
What I am missing/did wrong?
I have no knowledge in coding: thank you for help.
Giuseppe

Comment: Inspect curzoom and prevzoom - is the problem that sometimes they're equal?

Comment: I just use currzoom on zoomstart hoping it detects if I zoomIn or zoomOut in order to do_something1 or to do_something2.. Anyway it works if I start zommingOut. If I change diff>0 with diff>=0 the same behaviour occurs....i.e it should do_something1 when I zoomIn even if currzoom equals prevzoom but it does not..

Comment: See [comment in Leaflet/Leaflet PR#1600](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1600#issuecomment-77186793): "_e.g. when you start pinching a map with your fingers on mobile, `zoomstart` should fire, but you don't know where you end up._"